# Converting WSE example code to WCF

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, wse

I am new to both WSE and WCF and I am trying to consume a web service using WCF but all the example documentation is for VS2005 + WSE.  This web service uses WS-Security 1.0.  I have added a service reference through visual studio but I am at a loss on how to do the equivalent of the code below in WCF:

```
// 1. Initialize the web service proxy
PartnerAPIWse integrationFramework = new PartnerAPIWse();

// 2. Set the username/password. This is using the Username token of WS-Security 1.0
UsernameTokenProvider utp = new UsernameTokenProvider("username", "password");
integrationFramework.SetClientCredential<UsernameToken>(utp.GetToken());

// 3. Declare the policy
Policy policy = new Policy(new UsernameOverTransportAssertion());
integrationFramework.SetPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: For future reference: WSE is obsolete. All new web service development should be done using WCF, and WSE code should be retired ASAP.

Comment: Some companies have a huge investment in WSE.  It's not always a commercially sound decision to abandon a particular technology generation because the vendor has put something new out.

Comment: This question and answer are helpful; however, in some cases, the resulting security header lacks a "nonce" and other critical elements / attributes.  The following question and answer address this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102693/error-in-wcf-client-consuming-axis-2-web-service-with-ws-security-usernametoken-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending a day doing some experimentation I figured out how to convert this code.  The key was setting up the bindings on the WCF proxy that VS2008 makes correctly.

1. Add a service reference pointing to the WSDL
2. Open App.config / Web.config and locate the system.serviceModel section.  Change the security mode on the default soapbinding to be TransportWithMessageCredential.  Here is what my file looked like after the change:

   ```
           <basicHttpBinding>
           <binding name="SoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                   maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
               <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                   <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
                   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
               </security>
           </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
   ```
3. Change the example code above to look like this

   ```
   Dim integrationFramework As New SoapClient()
   integrationFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username"
   integrationFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"
   ```

TransportWithMessageCredential is equivalent to UsernameOverTransportAssertion policy under WSE 3.0