# Error in WCF client consuming Axis 2 web service with WS-Security UsernameToken PasswordDigest authentication scheme

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, apache-axis, ws-security

I have a WCF client connecting to a Java based Axis2 web service (outside my control). It is about to have WS-Security applied to it, and I need to fix the .NET client. However, I am struggling to provide the correct authentication. I am aware that WSE 3.0 might make it easier, but I would prefer not to revert to an obsolete technology.

Similar issues (unsolved), include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886987/web-service-request-authentication), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368131/wcf-configuration-for-soap-plain-text-password-authentication-over-ssl) and [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10050148/consume-java-webservice-w.aspx).

The SOAP message **should** look like this:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken>
  <wsse:Username><!-- Removed--></wsse:Username> 
  <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"><!-- Removed--></wsse:Password> 
  <wsse:Nonce><!-- Removed--></wsse:Nonce> 
  <wssu:Created>2010-05-28T12:50:33.675+01:00</wssu:Created> 
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

However, mine looks like this:

```
<s:Header>
<h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></h:Security>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
<u:Created>2010-06-23T10:31:23.441Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2010-06-23T10:36:23.441Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-d329b3b2-6a1f-4882-aea6-ec6b8a492de7-1">
<o:Username>
<!-- Removed-->
</o:Username>
<o:Password>
<!-- Removed-->
</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

My client looks like this:
P.S. Note the **required** SecurityHeaderType param. What is that?

```
public MyAck SendRequest(MyRequest request)
{
 RemoteServicePortTypeClient client = new RemoteServicePortTypeClient();

 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "JAY";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "AND";

    // what is the difference between the two different Credential types??
    //client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "SILENT";
    //client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "BOB";

 SecurityHeaderType sht = new SecurityHeaderType();
 //sht.Any = ???; // How do I use this???
 //sht.AnyAttr = ???; // How do I use this ???

 // SecurityHeaderType is a required parameter
 return client.RemoteServiceOperation_Provider(sht, request);
}
```

Current binding is as follows:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I've also tried a custom binding and got a similar error:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="myCustomBindingConfig">
    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11"
      securityHeaderLayout="Strict"
      includeTimestamp="false"></security>
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

And endpoint (Address obviously changed...):

```
<endpoint address="https://www.somecompany.com/uat/axis/services/RemoteServiceOperation_Provider"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding"
      contract="RemoteService.RemoteServicePortType"
      name="RemoteService_UAT" />
```

The custom fault that is being returned is as follows:

```
<ErrorID>0</ErrorID>
<ErrorType>UNEXPECTED</ErrorType>
<ErrorDescription><![CDATA[Array index out of range: 0]]></ErrorDescription>
<TimeStamp>2010-06-23T13:28:54Z</TimeStamp>
```

I've read lots about custom headers, tokens, bindings and my brain is completely confused. Can anyone suggest a step by step process for sending the message in the right format?

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872(VS.90).aspx) appears to be the way forward for WCF, using custom tokens, but how should one apply the digest and nonce as required?

Any help welcomed.

## UPDATE

I've had some limited success. I've used the Microsoft.Web.Services3 library to create a UsernameToken with the correct digest. I've then created my own custom behavior and in the BeforeSendRequest method I've done the following to inject the header:

```
object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    UsernameToken ut = new UsernameToken("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);

    XmlElement securityElement = ut.GetXml(new XmlDocument());

    MessageHeader myHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", securityElement, false);
    request.Headers.Add(myHeader);

    return Convert.DBNull;
}
```

I add the behavior like so:

```
CustomBehavior behavior = new CustomBehavior("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

I can now see the headers going across:

```
<s:Header>
<Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c6aeb72d-4d36-4650-abd3-33cc66caac6d" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-06-24T16:23:58Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</Security>
</s:Header>
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns="">soapenv:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xmlns="">WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (WSSecurityEngine: Callback supplied no password for: USERNAME)</faultstring>
<faultactor xmlns="">urn:Remote_Provider</faultactor>
<detail xmlns="">
<CUSTOMError xmlns="urn:customerror:v01">
<ErrorID>0</ErrorID>
<ErrorType>UNEXPECTED</ErrorType>
<ErrorDescription><![CDATA[WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (WSSecurityEngine: Callback supplied no password for: USERNAME)]]></ErrorDescription>
<TimeStamp>2010-06-24T17:23:59Z</TimeStamp>
</CUSTOMError>
</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

There appears to be a missing **Type** attribute on the password node:

```
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"
```

However, I'm not sure if the security tracing and logging settings are blanket removing the attributes and content of those nodes. I've attempted to use the [logKnownPii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730318.aspx) setting in the diagnostics logging, but the security information remains obscured. Any ideas on that one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that the UPDATE from my question actually works:

```
object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    UsernameToken ut = new UsernameToken("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);

    XmlElement securityElement = ut.GetXml(new XmlDocument());

    MessageHeader myHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", securityElement, false);
    request.Headers.Add(myHeader);

    return Convert.DBNull;
}
```

And the client:

```
CustomBehavior behavior = new CustomBehavior("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

The error message was unrelated. The security header works with a very simple basicHttpBinding:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicSOAPBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like something that may disappear in the future. The ONVIF spec now says : "The services defined in this standard shall be protected using digest authentication according
to [RFC 2617] with the exception of legacy devices supporting [WS-UsernameToken]." source : https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v1706.pdf 5.12.1

Answer (score 2):

This question is well written -- many thanks.  In reference to @Junto's "How do I use this" comment, it turns out that the SecurityHeader param on the service method can be used to add the header.  I've included an example below.  I believe that what's happening is that the SvcUtil.exe tool is barfing when trying to read the WS* DTDs.  This is not obvious when you use the "Add Service Reference" wizard.  But it is very obvious when you run svcutil.exe from the command line.  Because svcutil.exe fails to read the WS* DTD's, the SecurityHeader object is not well developed. But Microsoft gives you an out with the .Any property.  You can serialize the UsernameToken class right into the .Any property and your header will be added to the message.  Again, thanks for this excellent question.

How to use the SecurityHeader parameter to add a UsernameToken security header:

**Required tools:**

> Fiddler2 (or similar) -- you really can't figure any of this out without inspecting
>   the http headers.

**Required Reference:**

```
Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll -- you can reference this 2.0 framework assembly from your 4.0 assembly
```

**WCF service call:**

```
// Initialization of the service...
_service = new MyService("MyEndpoint", RemoteUri);

// etc.    

// Calling the service -- note call to GetSecurityHeader()
_service.ServiceAction(GetSecurityHeader(), "myParam1");

// etc.

/// <summary>
/// Construct the WSE 3.0 Security Header
/// </summary>
private SecurityHeader GetSecurityHeader()
{
    SecurityHeader h = new SecurityHeader();
    UsernameToken t = new UsernameToken(RemoteLogin, RemotePassword, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
    h.Any = new XmlElement[1];
    h.Any[0] = t.GetXml(new XmlDocument());
    return h;
}
```

**App.config:**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="1048576" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myservice.com/service.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"              contract="MyContract"
          name="MyEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently and gave up searching for a non-WSE solution. After a couple days of pulling my hair out I ended downloading the WSE 3.0 SDK, generating a proxy class using WseWsdl3.exe, and creating a new policy for the UsernameToken. I was up and running in 15min.  The following is currently working for me.

```
RemoteService service = new RemoteService();  //generated class

UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(username, password, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
Policy policy = new Policy();
policy.Assertions.Add(new UsernameOverTransportAssertion());

service.SetClientCredential(token);
service.SetPolicy(policy);

var result = service.MethodCall();
```