# Java digest Web service Call using c#

Tags: c#, web-services, digest

I have a C#  app that can consume Java Digest Web Services . I then supply a
System.Net.NetworkCredential but still get an Unauthorized
(401) error from the host.
I am using the visual studio 2008 .
Any Suggestions appreciated?

MY Client Code:

```
 webservice Client=new Client();
            NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user1", "test13");
            CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCredentialCache.Add(myUrl, "Digest", myNetworkCredential);
            Client.PreAuthenticate = true;
            Client.Credentials = myNetworkCredential;
            Client.GetData();
```

We Getting an Unauthorized(401) error. Do you have an idea of what can cause the problem?

Comment: Without the *code* it's impossible to help. Most likely you are sending the wrong credentials, or the account doesn't have permission

Comment: BTW what do you mean by `Java digest Web service call`? Are you trying to use digest authentication? There are already [duplicate answers for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686833/consuming-a-web-service-using-digest-authentication)

Comment: Yes We are using digest authentication.    I checked this web service with SOAPUI tool and we are getting proper response even with PHP language it is working fine but in case of C# code we are getting problem.

Comment: Code to call Web Service:     webservice Client=new Client();
                NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user1", "test13");
                CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
                myCredentialCache.Add(myUrl, "Digest", myNetworkCredential);
                Client.PreAuthenticate = true;
                Client.Credentials = myNetworkCredential;
                Client.GetData();

Comment: Please help on the above issue..